# How to specify variant directory in SConscript

Tags: scons

I am new to SCons and need help in understanding why my build script is not producing the required output. Any pointers to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my file structure:

```
.
├── prog_1
│   ├── hello.c
│   └── SConscript
└── SConstruct
```

Heres how I want it to look after running `scons -u` from the prog_1 sub-directory.

```
.
├── prog_1
│   ├── build
│   │   └── hello.o
│   ├── hello.c
│   ├── prog_1.out
│   └── SConscript
└── SConstruct
```

Contents of the `SConstruct` file:

```
env = Environment()
env['CC'] = 'gcc'
env['CCFLAGS'] = Split("""
-std=c99
-Wall
""")

Export('env')
```

Contents of the `prog_1/SConscript` file:

```
Import('env')

build = env.Clone()
build['CCFLAGS'] += ['-DENABLE_FEAT_1']

build.VariantDir('build', '.', duplicate=0)
build_src = build.Glob('build/*.c')

import os
prog_name = os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]
build.Program(prog_name +'.out', source = build_src)

Clean('.','build')
```

When I run `scons -u` from the prog_1 sub-directory, I get this as output:

```
[ananya@firenze prog_1]$ scons -u
scons: Entering directory `/home/ananya/test/scons-test'
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `prog_1' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

Edit: Added output description.

Edit2: Added script correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  You just need to specify your SConscript file in the SConstruct file.

Your `SConstruct` should be as follows...

```
import os
env = Environment()
env['CC'] = 'gcc'
env['CCFLAGS'] = Split("""
                       -std=c99
                       -Wall
                       """)

Export('env')

SConscript(os.path.join('prog_1', 'SConscript'))
```

Then when you run will get the following output...

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

>> tree ..
..
├── prog_1
│   ├── hello.c
│   └── SConscript
└── SConstruct

1 directory, 3 files

>> scons -u
scons: Entering directory `/nfs/users/bellockk/SandBox/tmp'
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: prog_1/build
gcc -o prog_1/build/hello.o -c -std=c99 -Wall -DENABLE_FEAT_1 prog_1/hello.c
gcc -o prog_1/prog_1.out prog_1/build/hello.o
scons: done building targets.

>> tree ..
..
├── prog_1
│   ├── build
│   │   └── hello.o
│   ├── hello.c
│   ├── prog_1.out
│   └── SConscript
└── SConstruct

2 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: An improvement would be to remove the call to VariantDir in the SConscript, and replace it with the variant_dir option in the call to SConscript() in the root SConstruct.

Comment: I'd like to second Brady, his approach is also the recommended setup as described in the UserGuide http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html , sect 15.1 "Specifying a Variant Directory Tree as Part of an SConscript Call"

Comment: I agree with the other comments above.  I only posted the fix, not any improvements.  The great thing about SCons though, just as with python, there is usually 5 or more different ways to accomplish the same goal.  Try the above suggestions if you can, and then use whatever works best for your particular application.